# What is composer? What is composer.json and composer.phar? And use of composer.json and why developer use it?

Tags: composer-php

I am new in composer functionality. I have no idea about composer.
I have find tutorial for it but they have no any strong tutorial to give proper instruction and example. Can you please suggest tutorial for the same.

Can we use “composer update” command without “composer.phar” file?
And what is the user of composer.phar file?

Comment: If you state that you read something that didn't help you, it is always worth linking to that page to avoid getting the same help again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see composer's [DOCS](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally):

> The installer will just check a few PHP settings and then download
>   composer.phar to your working directory. This file is the Composer
>   binary. It is a PHAR (PHP archive), which is an archive format for PHP
>   which can be run on the command line, amongst other things.

we can think of it as the program's executable.

you wouldn't be able to run composer without it.

> You can place the Composer PHAR anywhere you wish. If you put it in a
>   directory that is part of your PATH, you can access it globally. On
>   unixy systems you can even make it executable and invoke it without
>   directly using the php interpreter.

Comment: An example of using composer.phar: **php composer.phar --version**